# Exclude HTML tags from search in a string (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex

I have an array of titles which follow a similar format as below:

```
dolor ea consequat <span style="color: #fa8231;">&lt;deserunt&gt;</span> officia non elit <span style="color: #41B3A3;">&lt;aliqua&gt;</span> ex minim eu
```

which are displayed to the user using the `dangerouslysetInnerHTML` property.

They are displayed to the user in a list and the user is able to filter the array given keyword(s) and the keyword(s) are highlighted. For example, searching for `dolor` would return the following string (using `replace()`) which is also displayed using the `dangerouslysetInnerHTML` property of ReactJS:

```
<span style="background-color: #6d7fcc; color: #fff">dolor</span> ea consequat <span style="color: #fa8231;">&lt;deserunt&gt;</span> officia non elit <span style="color: #41B3A3;">&lt;aliqua&gt;</span> ex minim eu
```

**NOTE**: The keyword can also include the text between the `&lt;`(<) and `&gt;`(>) tags and that text should also be highlighted. And the `<span>` tags in the original string should not be included in the search and replace.
Here's my RegEx code to search for the keyword(s) in the string:

```
const regexStr = `${keyword}(?=[^>]*<)`;
const highlightRegex = new RegExp(regexStr, 'gi');
```

The problem I am encountering is that the search does not include the last part of the string (anything past the last `</span>`) in the search, so `ex minim eu` is not included.
I am trying to learn RegEx, so my knowledge is weak.
Could someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UDPATE 1:

I added this to my regex and that seemed to have work. Not sure if this is the best or most efficient way. Would still love any feedback!

```
const regexStr = `${keyword}((?=[^>]*<)|(?![^<]*>))`;
```